# Div disappearing when saving stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I'm using coda and live preview, when I save this CSS file, my #middle div disappears? If I then just hit enter anywhere on the screen, it reappears where it should be. However then if I re-save the file again, it disappears and my #footer shoots up to the top of the page. I'm not making any changes to any of the code so I'm having trouble figuring out exactly why this is happening, any ideas? And on http://jsfiddle.net/UkYBy/ it doesn't show the #middle or #footer at all? Here is what it should look like: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14754850/Screen%20shot%202012-11-20%20at%2010.22.40%20PM.jpg

Thanks!

PS. It's not letting me post this question without posting some code in this post so this is the html:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
                    </ul></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

    <div id="middle"></div>        
    <div id="footer"></div>



</div>
</body>
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close three tags in the CSS.

```
#menu ul li ul { 
 display: none;  


#menu ul li ul li {
 background-color: #2d2d2d; 

#menu ul li ul li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
```

Needs to be:

```
#menu ul li ul { 
 display: none;  
}

#menu ul li ul li {
 background-color: #2d2d2d; 
}

#menu ul li ul li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 15px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UkYBy/1/

Comment: Sorry, I had deleted some comments before copying to the fiddle and accidentally erased the closing brackets. I still get the error with those brackets closed.. but you made me focus in the right area because I actually had an extra closing bracket on one line and thats what was messing it up. Amazing how one little character out of place can drive you crazy :)